# How to change part of all the img src on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am looking for is how to change all the img src on the page using java script.

if say:

```
<img src="myimg1-small.png"></img>
<img src="myimg2-small.gif"></img>
<img src="myimg3-small.jpg"></img>
.......
```

I only want to change the "-small" to "-large" and keep the first part and extensions.

If anyone could help me out that would be great thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the JQuery code.

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace(/-small\./g,'-large'));
});
```

Comment: Why use a regular expression?  You're just making the browser work harder than it needs to.  Simply replace the string `'-small'` with the string `'-large'`!

Answer (score 1):

If you want regular js:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src.replace('small','large');
}
```

Comment: Thank You for this I am just learning JavaScript, I could change the whole src but could not figure how to just change end. Now I can have one function for the whole site that will serve up a smaller img file for mobile thanks again

Comment: could you also show me how I can change the link that's wrapping the image in the same way replace the small for large Thanks again

Comment: If this solved your issue, you may want to mark this as the accepted answer. Also, if the link is the direct parent of the image and you want to do the changes in the same for loop, after `imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src.replace('small','large');` you can put `imgs[i].parentNode.href = imgs[i].parentNode.href.replace('test','testing');`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img[src^="myimg1-small"]').attr('src', function() {
    return this.src.replace('small', 'large');
});
```

Comment: +1 at least one elegant jquery solution :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('-small','-large'));
});
```

Edit:  I notice several of us answered essentially the same within a minute or so of each other.  But, a couple of notes:

(1) Don't use a regular expression when a simple string match will do the job more efficiently.

(2) I included the hyphen (-) in my match so as not to accidentally confuse it with an image name that has the string 'small' without the hyphen.  After all, if the image is of a small flower, for example, and the image name is 'smallflower-small.jpg', the match that doesn't use the hyphen breaks.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('img').each(function (){
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('small', 'medium'))
    })
});
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KgXLY/)